# Why the tab widget is above the content in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Currently I work on a tabhost layout.

In most android app the layout is:

```
tab1 | tab 2
____________

Tab 1 content 
(if I press on tab1)
```

However, what I would like to achieve is

```
Tab 1 content 
(if I press on tab1)
____________
tab1 | tab 2
```

Here is the main xml (backbone of app) :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The tab content layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#31152C"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MonitoringActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The main class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ctx = this;

    gs = (MyApp) getApplication();

    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator(""),Home.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("carpark").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_park)), CarPark.class,null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("shop").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_shop)), Shop.class,null);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: add android :layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the tabWidget and it will be at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

you can add tabwidget to the bottom using the given code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout and orientation vertical at the same time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution using the support fragment tab host:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**tab1_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#31152C"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Home"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tab2_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#31152C"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Car Park"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tab3_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#31152C"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Shop"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
                Home.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
                CarPark.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
                Shop.class, null);
    }
}
```

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_view, container, false);
        return V;
    }
}
```

**CarPark.java**

```
public class CarPark extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_view, container, false);
        return V;
    }
}
```

**Shop.java**

```
public class Shop extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_view, container, false);
        return V;
    }
}
```