# Unfortunetly The program has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tabs, runtime-error

I wrote an android program. This has multiple tab.. I want when I clicked a tab(Tab1), the tab's special view(GalleryDemoActivity.java) was shown.. But the Program has stopped working and does'nt work truly !

The code is:
src/Tab.java:

```
package com.AdMd.Plant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Tabs extends Activity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, GalleryDemoActivity.class);
        spec1.setContent(photosIntent);
        spec1.setIndicator("اطلاعات گیاه");

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("گالری تصاویر");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
        spec3.setIndicator("گیاهان مشابه");
        spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);

    }    
}
```

The logcat messages are:

```
07-18 08:32:37.402: D/gralloc_goldfish(1068): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-18 08:32:40.272: D/AndroidRuntime(1068): Shutting down VM
07-18 08:32:40.272: W/dalvikvm(1068): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AdMd.Plant/com.AdMd.Plant.Tabs}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:680)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.AdMd.Plant.Tabs.onCreate(Tabs.java:32)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-18 08:32:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     ... 11 more
```

As you see in logcat, it said to me to have a activity Group, But when I use it, the program has some warning and it does'nt work again!

The warning are:

```
1.The method onCreate(Bundle) from the type ActivityGroup is deprecated
2.The type ActivityGroup is deprecated
```

What should I've done?
Thanks..

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?`

Comment: I know it! If you paying attention, I said after I see this message, I use activity Group but I have problems again..

Comment: Yes, I explained it in my post..

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485468/why-the-tab-widget-is-above-the-content-in-android/24486870#24486870

Comment: Please help, It does'nt solve..Help me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide action for every tab

just try this code

```
public class Tabs extends TabActivity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);


    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");

    spec1.setIndicator("اطلاعات گیاه");
    spec1.setContent(new Intent(this,GalleryDemoActivity.class));

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("گالری تصاویر");
spec2.setContent(new Intent(this,GalleryDemoActivity.class));


    TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec3.setIndicator("گیاهان مشابه");
    spec3.setContent(new Intent(this,GalleryDemoActivity.class));

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);
}
```

}

Comment: When I replace, it has warnings:

1.The method onCreate(Bundle) from the type ActivityGroup is deprecated
2.The type TabActivity is deprecated

Comment: When I change my code as you said, the program has stopped working again and it has warning too:

1.The method onCreate(Bundle) from the type ActivityGroup is deprecated 2.The type TabActivity is deprecated

Comment: Insted of this : TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost); try this : TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);