# Exception raised during rendering: TabHost requires FrameLayout with id "android:id/tabs"

Tags: android

I'm having an awful issue with TabHost inside my app. Basically, I am renaming all the id's how it wishes me to. But nothing is changing and it's still having rendering issues.

Picture for reference:

[image]

Here is that whole top snippet

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FindMyCar"
    android:id="@+id/idhere">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </TabHost>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/find"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485468/why-the-tab-widget-is-above-the-content-in-android/24486870#24486870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change id of TabWidget

`android:id="@id/tabs"`

by

```
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
```

And TabHost id by

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

FrameLayout id by

```
@android:id/tabcontent"
```

Here's the complete xml file

```
 <TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#696969" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `TabWidget` id to

```
 android:id="@android:id/tabs"
```

and also `TabHost` id to

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot from your IDE, you're missing the @ in front of android:id/tabs and android:id/tabcontent

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FindMyCar"
    android:id="@+id/idhere">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TabHost>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/find"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Haresh I applied this to my full XML and it's still throwing the same errors. "TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".

Full XML : http://pastebin.com/LfA1XQQD

Answer (score 0):

Android requires you to use its own defined id for `TabWidget` and `FrameLayout` inside the `TabHost`.
So change the id of `TabWidget` to `android:id="@android:id/tabs"`
and id of `FrameLayout` to `android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"`.
It shall work.