# Android activity with tabs: how do i get the Fragment instance behind the active tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a Activity that implements Tabs, basically I nicked this:

http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Which has a FragmentActivty adding tabs via a FragmentTabHost, like so:

```
mTabHost.addTab(
        mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1",
                getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
        FragmentTab.class, null); // how do i get back to the instance of Frgment tab???
```

I've added a TabChangeListener implementation and i'm getting notifications when a tab is set active,

BUT: I can't work out how to get to the FragmentTab instance behind the tab.

TIA

bg

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485468/why-the-tab-widget-is-above-the-content-in-android/24486870#24486870

Comment: how does this help? did you read the question at all?

Comment: I think that you can get the fragment from FragmentManager : getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tab1") ;

Comment: unfortunately, getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tab1"), only works after each tab has been bought to the front once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so you can't, well you can, but not really, the fragments dont exist until a tab is activated and when its deactivated the instance is paused.

Instead of trying to push data into the fragment/view as its activated, instead i'll get the view to pull the data in onCreateView - which is called each time the fragment is activated.